# Reading files in Ruby using regex

Tags: ruby, regex, file

I'm doing a project on a program that works like this:

- The user inputs the min and max difficulty they want.
- The program reads a file that has the questions and the answers, and prints the questions according to the difficulties.
- The user answers the question.
- The user's answer is compared to the actual answer.

The file looks like this:

```
D 1
Q What color are the clouds? 
A white
D 2 
Q What is 3 + 4? 
A 7
```

Say that I want to only grab `D 1` questions and answers. I would have to build regex that could read `D 1` and the next two lines (the `Q` and `A`). This is what I have come up with so far:

```
if(File.exists?("quiz.txt"))
  myFile = File.open("quiz.txt")
  array = Array.new
  i = 0
  q = nil
  d = nil
  a = nil
  answer_array = Array.new
  myFile.each{|line| 
    if(line =~ (/^D #{minimum}/ =~ line || /^D #{maximum}/ =~ line))
      d = line
      d.slice!(0..1)
     if(/^Q/ =~ line)
       i= i+1
       q = line
       q.slice!(0..1)
     end
      if(/^A/ =~ line)
        a = line
        a.slice!(0..1)
      end
    end
    }
```

What I have does not work. The first `if` statement that checks to see if the beginning of the like starts with a `D`, which has to always be true for the other two `if` statements to run, but they also have to read the next line, which would have to be outside of the `D` if statement. How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Ruby's Enumerable has a great method called [`slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before):

```
file = [
  'D 1',
  'Q What color are the clouds?',
  'A white',
  'D 2',
  'Q What is 3 + 4?',
  'A 7'
]

file.slice_before(/^D/).select{ |a| a.first[/^D 1/] }
=> [["D 1", "Q What color are the clouds?", "A white"]]
```

`slice_before` works on an array or an enumerable, so use something like [`File.open`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) to do that. An alternate is to use `File.read('path/to/file').split("\n")` or `File.readlines` to create an array, but you might as well use `open` and let Ruby work its magic against the returned enumerator:

```
File.open('path/to/file').slice_before(/^D/).select{ |a| a.first[/^D 1/] }
```

Comment: +1, I just _knew_ there was a method to do this elegantly but couldn't find it. Looked at `chunk`, `partition`...

Comment: It's been amazing to management how we've used it at work to rip through configurations from some of our equipment and extract just the stuff we needed. I've written similar code a couple times and finding it in Ruby only made me like the language that much more.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's each_slice could also be useful here;

```
File.open("test.txt").each_slice(3) do |(d, q, a)|
  if d > min && d < max
     ...
  end
end
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I think this is the most efficient approach. By the way, `IO` includes `Enumerable` and provides an `each` method, so you don't have to use `readlines`.

Comment: Another thing: in order to capture the array elements in the formal block argument declaration, you need parentheses: `|d, q, a|` should be `|(d, q, a)|`.